# Inject HTML in a GRMustacheTemplate

Tags: ios, objective-c, mustache

i created an HTML template file with following content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{stepOne}}
        </li>
        {{dynamicHtml}}
        <li>
            {{stepTwo}}
        </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Replacing the placeholders with normal text is going fine. But i want to include some HTML in one placeholder and that's not working as it is encoded from < to &lt;

```
    GRMustacheTemplate *demoTemplate = [GRMustacheTemplate templateFromContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:MUSTACHE_HTML_TEMPLATE ofType:@"html"] error:&error];

    NSDictionary *objectToRender = return @{
         @"stepOne" : @"Step 1",
         @"stepTwo" : @"Step 2",
         @"dynamicHtml" : @"<li>test</li>"
         };

    NSString *htmlString = [demoTemplate renderObject:objectToRender error:&error];
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like i could just use the special mustache syntax

```
{{&dynamicHtml}}
```

or

```
{{{dynamicHtml}}}
```